# Livereload no funciona en Sublime Text 4 (Brave Browser)

Tags: sublimetext

Buen día. He intentado instalar sin éxito Livereload para Sublime text 4.
Estoy usando la última versión (Build 4126) en el navegador **BRAVE**.

Ya probé agregando esto en preferences>package settings>Livereload

**Default:**

```
{
     "enabled_plugins": [
          "SimpleRefresh",
          "SimpleReloadPlugin"
     ]
}
```

**User:**

```
{
    "enabled_plugins":[
        "SimpleReloadPlugin",
        "SimpleRefresh"
    ]
}
```

En la configuración de la extensión le he autorizado el acceso a archivos locales, también reinicié el navegador y sublime text pero tampoco funcionó.

¿Se puede solucionar o hay algún paquete similar para Sublime Text 4?

Gracias de antemano.